# SSD with Windows 10 Pro is fully encrypted by VeraCrypt

Tags: veracrypt

My computer died. I took out a 240GB SSD with Windows 10 Pro. It is fully encrypted by VeraCrypt.

On another computer I tried to watch it through LiveCD and programs for working with hard drives. I didn’t see anything there since the encrypted SSD is in RAW format.

I installed VeraCrypt on another computer and tried to open this SSD, but VeraCrypt said that the password was incorrect. I tried many times... (it’s impossible to forget the password since I’ve been entering it every day for more than a year!!!)

Now I have restored the old computer, installed this SSD but the BIOS doesn't see it.

Previously, before the crash, it booted like this - first the BIOS, then a floating point appeared on the monitor. I entered the password and the Windows 10 Pro system began to boot.
But right now there’s no way.

From another computer, the is SSD visible in the Disk Manager, but cannot be opened.

I did not write to or erase anything from this SSD. I only watched it once via LiveCD.

Question for the experts:

If the SSD is not visible at all in BIOS, does this mean that the ESP is broken?

How to restore boot from this SSD so that it asks for a decryption password?

Comment: A partition cannot break. Unfortunately if Veracrypt cannot mount the disk you are out of options. Veracrypt is full disk encryption.

Comment: Do you have other backups of your data to recover from?

Comment: No. I didn't make a backup copy.
If I install Windows 10 on exactly the same disk and completely encrypt it in the same way. Is it possible to copy the Veracrypt loader from it and burn it to this disk?

Comment: The issue is resolved. The method of solving how I suggested. 1. Made SSD with Win10Pro and completely encrypted Veracrypt. At the end of encryption, Veracrypt made me a recovery folder with EFI folder.
2. made a boot flash drive exactly according to the description from the video https://youtu.be/c2uxcryhx7e

Comment: 3. I threw the EFI folder on this flash drive
And oh miracle. When loading from the flash drive, the long -awaited menu appeared.
Next, I chose a disk decryption. waited 5-6 hours ...
The disk has deciphered. All the necessary files are in order! But Winda lost the bootloader.
Loaded from the installation flash drive and on the command line prescribed the bootloader again.
All.